# pgfplots/standalone: setting new layer trims pgfplot output when called by \includestandalone[mode=tex]

Tags: pgfplots, standalone

For the main file

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
    layers/my layer set/.define layer set={
        background,main, rpim40 , rpim85 , sph,expint, exp
    }{},
    set layers=my layer set,
    mark layer=like plot,
    }

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \frame{
    \includestandalone[mode=tex,width=\textwidth]{exsurfacetikz}
  }
  \caption{My TikZ picture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

calling the following standalone pgfplot using `\includestandalone[mode=tex]` results in an **incorrectly** bottom-trimmed output only if I use the new layer set in the main file `set layers=my layer set`.

```
% exsurfacetikz.tex

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
%        view={0}{90},
        % you need to add this to get the desired result
        unbounded coords=jump,
        colorbar horizontal
    ]
        \addplot3 [
            surf,
        ] table [
            x=x,
            y=y,
            z expr={\thisrow{z} == 100 ? NaN : \thisrow{z}},
        ] {
            x   y       z
            3.1 1.00    21.8
            3.1 0.98    19.16666667
            3.1 0.96    17.83333333
            3.1 0.94    16.16666667
            3.1 0.92    15.5
            3.1 0.90    14.83333333
            3.1 0.88    14.16666667
            3.1 0.86    13.5
            3.1 0.84    12.83333333
            3.1 0.82    12.16666667
            3.1 0.80    12.16666667
            3.1 0.78    11.5
            3.1 0.76    100
            3.1 0.74    100

            3.3 1       21.83333333
            3.3 0.98    20.5
            3.3 0.96    18.5
            3.3 0.94    16.83333333
            3.3 0.92    15.5
            3.3 0.9     14.83333333
            3.3 0.88    14.16666667
            3.3 0.86    13.5
            3.3 0.84    12.83333333
            3.3 0.82    12.16666667
            3.3 0.8     12.16666667
            3.3 0.78    11.5
            3.3 0.76    11.5
            3.3 0.74    11.5
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]